# How do browsers handle HTTP 410 Gone?

Tags: http, browser, http-headers, browser-history

Given an API that lets you create short-lived, auto-expiring resources – is it a good idea to respond with HTTP 410 Gone when browsers request expired resources?

How do browsers handle this? Specifically: Do they remove the URL from their history?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome and Firefox do not remove url from the history if 410 status code is returned. For other browsers you can test this with http://httpstat.us.

But according to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.9) using 410 for expired resources seems to be semantically correct:

> The 410 (Gone) status code indicates that access to the target
> resource is no longer available at the origin server and that this
> condition is likely to be permanent.  If the origin server does not
> know, or has no facility to determine, whether or not the condition
> is permanent, the status code 404 (Not Found) ought to be used
> instead.
>
> The 410 response is primarily intended to assist the task of web
> maintenance by notifying the recipient that the resource is
> intentionally unavailable and that the server owners desire that
> remote links to that resource be removed.  Such an event is common
> for limited-time, promotional services and for resources belonging to
> individuals no longer associated with the origin server's site.  It
> is not necessary to mark all permanently unavailable resources as
> "gone" or to keep the mark for any length of time -- that is left to
> the discretion of the server owner.